# Formik object doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, formik

I created a custom input called `<FormInput>` and applied `useField()` and `useFormikContext()` to it:

```
const [field, meta] = useField(props);
const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
```

`<FormInput>` is part of a library called `UI`. I'm importing the library and trying to create a very simple form to test, a single field, the only validation being that it's required:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { DataContext } from "../../context/DataContext";
import * as UI from "@tui/uilibrary";
import { composeThemeFromProps } from "@css-modules-theme/react";
import styles from "./EnrollStep5.module.scss";

import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const EnrollStep5 = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(DataContext);
  const theme = composeThemeFromProps(styles, [context, props]);

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: "",
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      })}
    >
      {(props) => {
        <Form className={theme.EnrollStep2}>
          <UI.FormInput type={"text"} name={"name"} label={"Name"} />
        </Form>;
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default EnrollStep5;
```

This comes up blank. The Formik object appears in the Component browser, but shows as if it has no children. I have the feeling this is just due to inexperience and that I'm close. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**In short:**
Wrap the `<Form>...</Form>` in (parantheses) instead of {curly braces}.

**Little more detailed:**
So basically what is happening in your code with the curly braces is you are entering the callback function. So the `<Form>...</Form>` is just floating around somewhere in the function body. What you intend to do is to return it.
So you can either add a return statement (`return <Form>...</Form>;`) inside the curly braces or directly return the value without entering the function body. E.g. like `(props) => <Form>...</Form>` or `(props) => (<Form>...</Form>)`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<Field>` component inside of `<Form>...</Form>` like this:

```
<Formik initialValues={{name: ""}}>
  <Form>
    <Field name="name" placeholder="Name:"></Field>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

`<Field>` component will pass their value to **formik** and it can handle submit and etc.

You can create custom **Field** component:

```
<Formik initialValues={{ name: "" }}>
  <Form>
    <Field name="name" placeholder="Name:">
       {({ field }) => (
         <CustomInput {..field} />
       )}
    </Field>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

`<CustomInput>` should include a **html** `<input/>` element or you can use flowbite, materialUI input components like this.

If you want to pass **error** or **touched** objects to custom components you should try this solution:

```
<Formik initialValues={{ name: "" }}>
    {({ values, errors, touched }) => (
      <Form>
        <Field name="name" placeholder="Name:">
          {({ field }) => (
            <CustomInput {...field} errors={errors} value={values}/>
          )}
        </Field>
      </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Comment: Learn more about `<Field/>` component here: [https://formik.org/docs/api/field](https://formik.org/docs/api/field)